# ServiceStack session info error

Tags: facebook, authentication, servicestack

The incorrect ВisplayName through the entrance on Facebook:

[image]

any ideas how to fix without changing native SS code? )

PS:if sign in with Google all the rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DisplayName comes from Facebook OAuth, you can override them on the `OnAuthenticated()` Hook on the [User Session or Auth Events](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#session-events).

To change what information Facebook is used you can create a custom Auth Provider that inherits from `FacebookAuthProvider` and [overrides LoadUserAuthInfo()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/f68b30a4af8afaf15a67cca2b92baabcbad25d13/src/ServiceStack/Auth/FacebookAuthProvider.cs#L108).

Comment: #mythz, hi, thanks for feedback, I know I can override the name in OnAuthenticated(), and I know that during registration the user provides the service, but I'm changing the UserName after registration, for Google everything is working but Facebook not, after next login it's reset to default.

Comment: #mythz, to solve the problem I did, but it seems so wrong...
[Sample link](http://prntscr.com/ecxxd1)

Comment: @MherArsh you don't need to assign it twice just once will do.